# RubyMotion - Debugging

Tags: debugging, rubymotion

I'm wondering what the best way for me to debug a rubymotion application is. I'm new to this area and have been playing around with breakpoints - however I don't seem to have access to any variables for me to inspect.

Is there any gem / command I can use that is the equivalent of raise / binding.pry in rails, that would let me call for example @posts from the terminal after hitting an error / raise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try asking in [the development team's slack channel](https://motioneers.herokuapp.com/) maybe?

From the official [RubyMotion Debugging Guide for iOS and OS X](http://www.rubymotion.com/developers/guides/manuals/cocoa/debugging/)

> The LLDB support is at this point experimental and also quite low-level. Our goal is to build a higher-level, friendlier debugger on top of LLDB that will provide a better experience for Ruby developers.